# Joining to another table or not?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Basically I have 2 tables. `users` and `users_activity`. I use mysql table and the count of users almost 5000. Each users have many activities, about 50-150 activities. When I want to fetch the list of users table (ten by ten), I have to display user's last activity date. In this case I have two options:

**First Option:**

I Add column `last_activity` to `users` table and do select like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC, lIMIT 0, 10
```

If I want to add a new activity:

```
INSERT INTO users_activity (userId, date) VALUES(19, "2016-04-06")

UPDATE users SET last_activity = "2016-04-06" WHERE id = 19 LIMIT 1
```

If I want to cancel the `last_activity`:

```
DELETE FROM users_activity WHERE activity_id = 100 LIMIT 1

SELECT date FROM users_activity WHERE userId = 19 ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1
```

Using this select, I am able to fetch the last date FROM `users_activity` table and use it in update sql.

```
UPDATE users SET last_activity = "2016-04-02" WHERE id = 19 LIMIT 1
```

**Second option:**

I remove column `last_activity` from `users` table and do select like this:

```
SELECT
  users.*,
  users_activity.date
FROM
   users
LEFT JOIN
   users_activity ON users_activity.userId = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY
   users.id DESC, users_activity.date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

If I want to add a new activity:

```
INSERT INTO users_activity (userId, date) VALUES(19, "2016-04-06")
```

if I want to cancel the `last_activity`:

```
DELETE FROM users_activity WHERE activity_id = 100 LIMIT 1
```

I use Mysql. Both tables are `innoDB`.

In this situation, which way would you recommend me and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I want to say your insert statement syntax is wrong. Because insert statement does not work with where clause.
If I understant you correctly you want to show user's informations and it's last action date. If your tables well indexed that you can do it the next query:

```
SELECT u.*, a.action_date FROM users u
LEFT JOIN users_activity a ON a.userId = u.userId
GROUP BY a.userId
ORDER BY a.action_date desc
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use your second scenario, two tables. That way you don't have to worry about managing the last activity date as well as the activity list, and you can always get the last activity date by selecting max(users_activity_date) per user with the left join and grouping per user.

As a disclaimer, you may want to try both and see what is more performant in your situation.  Scenario 1 gives performance benefits to your reporting query, but Scenario 2 will give the activity tracking updates the performance nod.   With any performance questions, no best practice or advice can truly replace testing in your environment with realistic load.

Comment: The drawback of the 2-nd option is that it requires a somewhat complicated query to get a decent performance compared to the 1-st (you need to have `Using index for group-by` in the query plan to get the same performance as option 1).

Comment: @Vatev I agree, but each step requires exactly one operation in the second scenario.  Also, he's only selecting 10 user's at a time, and if we're tracking user activity, it's probably more important that the activity tracking be performant then the reporting component.

Comment: In my experience in most cases it's better to make the reads simple and the writes complicated. It depends on how many queries will need the `last_acticity` when join-ing `users`.

Comment: @Vatev Point taken, I have added a disclaimer to reflect the basis of our discussion.  With this few rows, however, I will recommend simplicity over potential over-optimization every time.